# Remove unwanted pages from PWA

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA application from my wordpress website and it is working fine. Now, when the user gets logged in to the Admin panel from PWA, I want to hide some tabs and pages. That pages needs to be available on the website but will be removed or hidden in the Application. How can I achieve this ?

Please help.